# TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: web3js, mapping

I am trying to read a mapping inside my smart contract that looks like this:

```
mapping(address => User) public users;
```

My web3js code looks like this. I am trying to read mapping users inside the smart contract:

```
var contractAddress='0x3aacc70dced50f8c6c1951f27d505d2ad165b373';
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
contractInstance.users.call(web3.eth.accounts[0], function(err, result){
 if(!err){
    alert(result)
 }
 });
```

However I get the error like below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Can someone help me resolve this

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a mapping public getter without sending a key with it.
Also you are returning a Struct which is not possible yet (AFAIK) 
check this answer for more : 
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/302

If that is not fix your problem, you may need to check your `.json` built by truffle or try to deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

When arrays are returned with public getters, you need to specific the index that you are looking for.

You may find the following article useful [structs from public functions](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-returning-structs-from-public-functions-e78e48efb378) and/or just manually loop through each index and add it to a json object.